# How to configure azure webjob to run every 30 seconds

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

This should be quick - I know how to run .net webjobs down to every minute..
 eg 0 0/1 * 1/1 * *

but I would like to run every 10 seconds!! I can find unix methods, but no azure webjobs / ,net examples..

Comment: Try dividing minutes by 60*10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To schedule a triggered WebJob you need to add a schedule property to the `settings.job` file. The value of the schedule is cron expression that has 6 fields to represent the schedule: `{second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day of the week}`.

So you just add the following to a `settings.job` file if you want to run every 10 seconds.

```
{
  "schedule": "*/10 * * * * *"
}
```

> If your app runs continuous or scheduled WebJobs, enable **Always On** to ensure that the WebJobs run reliably. This feature is **available only in the Basic, Standard, and Premium pricing tiers**.

For more details, you could refer to this [article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

Comment: thanks  - obvious, but sometime one can't see the word for the trees (the downside of being a solo developer).

Answer (score -1):

the patterns seems to be like Cron schedule jobs

*/10 * * * *

https://crontab.guru

Comment: This will run every ten minutes, you need an extra asterisk as per @joey-cai answer below